# I need a mouse event but unsure

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, glut

I have an assignment due and I need a mouse event, I have a keyboard event which closes the window.

How would I create a mouse event that changes the background colour? so far I have this. It only works when you drag the bottom corner of the screen though.

```
void mouse (int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
        if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
            glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
        glFlush();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `glutPostRedisplay()` to the end of the `if` block to tell GLUT to queue up a window repaint event.